# Variable changes unexpectedly after commands are run in R

Tags: linux, r

I'm a new R user, and work requires that I use R on linux. I am running into a very strange problem, and hope some of you expert users can provide a solution. :)

I have a large dataset with >200,000 observations/participants and >300 variables, that involves subsetting from various baseline datasets to create the working dataset.

My issue is that an essential variable changes some times when I run the length command. 
"Withdrawlevel" is the variable that changes. This is how this variable should be:

```
describe(tbl$Withdrawlevel)
tbl$Withdrawlevel
      n missing  unique    Mean
   2833  218988       3   1.474
```

I then run several length commands like the following because I'm interested in getting the number of participants that meet certain criteria. 
For example:

```
length(which(tbl[,'Reg_age_dob']>=18 & as.Date(tbl[,'QuestionnaireEndDate'])>='2013-07-21' & as.Date(tbl[,'QuestionnaireEndDate'])< '2013-07-28' & (is.na(tbl$Withdrawlevel) | (tbl$Withdrawlevel!=3) & (tbl$WithdrawDate<'2013-07-28')) | ((tbl$Withdrawlevel=3) & (tbl$WithdrawDate>='2013-07-28'))  ))
```

And, then Withdrawlevel variable changes:

```
describe(tbl$Withdrawlevel)                                                   tbl$Withdrawlevel
      n missing  unique    Mean
 221821       0       1       3
```

Is the length command described above doing something to this variable, because my understanding is that it shouldn't. And, I have run many similar commands with this data, and this issue doesn't occur after each one.

Any insight into what is going on and how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tbl$Withdrawlevel=3` assigns the value `3` to all observations of `tbl$Withdrawlevel`.  You meant `tbl$Withdrawlevel==3`.

Answer (score 1):

(Joshua's answer is correct.) In the future you can protect yourself against this sort of error by using `with`:

```
with( tbl, length( which(Reg_age_dob >=18 & 
      as.Date(QuestionnaireEndDate) >='2013-07-21' & 
      as.Date(QuestionnaireEndDate) < '2013-07-28' & 
      ( is.na(tbl$Withdrawlevel) | (Withdrawlevel!=3) & ( WithdrawDate <'2013-07-28') )  | 
      ( (tbl$Withdrawlevel=3) & ( WithdrawDate >='2013-07-28') )  )
                   )
     )
```

The point is that this does not have the danger of corrupting your data object *and* it's also much easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using booleans for all your expressions in your which function.  Make sure to use `==` instead of `=` which returns a value of True or False rather than setting the variable to equal the value.